# Jquery scrollintoview not working Error - Property Undefined

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Can anybody see why this is not working, the element is fine. i think see below, Help greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```js
//check for key press and check for errors in form fields
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keyup(checksub);
});
//checks for errors in forms on submit - callled from checkerrors.
function checksub() {
  checkphone();
}



function checkphone() {


  var phone = $("#phonevalue").val();
  var phoneReg = /^[0-9][0-9 \r\n]{10,11}$/;


  if (!phoneReg.test(phone)) {
    localStorage.setItem('error', 'true');
    event.preventDefault(); //ERROR THROWN HERE

    $("#phonefooter").text("11-12 Numbers Please!"), $("#phonevalue").addClass("errorclass"), $("#phonevalue").removeClass("noerrorclass"), $('#phonefooter').css('color', 'red'), $("phonefooter").get(0).scrollIntoView();
  }

  if (phoneReg.test(phone)) {
    localStorage.setItem('error', 'false');

    $("#phonefooter").text("phone Number Is Good, Thanks!"), $("#phonevalue").addClass("noerrorclass"), $("#phonevalue").removeClass("errorclass"), $('#phonefooter').css('color', '#4caf50');
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>

  <div class='listtitle' title='Enter The Sellers Phone Number'>Phone Number<br>
    <h5>Enter Sellers Mobile or Phone Number</h5>
  </div>


  <input type='numbers' pattern=".{10,13}" min="10" max="13" class='text' name='phone1' id='phonevalue' style='min-width:260px; max-width:300px;' value='<?php echo $phone1; ?>' required>

  <div id='phonefooter' class='phonefooter'>Max Numbers: 20</div>


</div>
```

The error thrown is

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of undefined

Any Ideas as to why?

Thanks Again.

Comment: <script src="../js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

Comment: seems to run okay, harder to tell on first glance i suppose, without the php-generated html. Have you checked the path to the jquery library is ok?

Comment: the stacksnippet will reflect a jquery path coded by stackoverflow

Comment: There was some edits made... And it is now highly improbable that the error is thrown on the actually indicated line.

Comment: i only edited the jquery version to 1.11, otherwise the code is your own

Comment: i tried the suggested jquery still no avail... i have 1.12.4 , and it supports scrollintoview so im not sure.

Comment: Melissa: change the comas `,` for semi-colon `;` after each jQuery commands. And indent your code correctly. Re-run it and if there still is an error, indicate the correct line.

Comment: input doesn't need an end tag, take it  off, also it should be number (singular ) not numbers

Comment: thank you. i removed the end tags ect, but still got the problem,  Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of undefined

Comment: Try `$(".phonefooter")[0].scrollIntoView();` lolll I just saw it... The dot indicating a class was missing in the selector. `$(".phonefooter").get(0).scrollIntoView();` should also work.

Comment: Voting to close as it's a typo.

Comment: thank you, you solved the mystery..it now scrolls to the element...

Comment: well, actually. it scrolls to bottom of page regardless of element ..hmmm -1 1 sec only just sae the edited update..il check again

Comment: Yes working, allthough its scrolling right to the top of the screen and my navbar is hiding the element then, but il tweak things and get it right, THANK YOU Louys Patrice Bassette

Comment: Try `$(".phonefooter").get(0).scrollIntoView(false);`... See the `false` ? that is for align to bottom of viewport, instead of top. The element you align is below the input... ;) [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Answer (score -1):

```
> This < is not the solution - far from it - it was just a dot.
```

$("phonefooter").get(0).scrollIntoView();

There is an Ajax function called get, which request a server from the page, but when used with a number it's like an index for the DOM context.

There is a npm plugin called jQuery.scrollintoview() (all in lowercase) and then there is HTML DOM function scrollIntoView(). One you need to install and the other is already there.

Comment: In this case, `.get(0)` is not an Ajax function... It's [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) the DOM element at index 0. And [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) is pure JS, not a plugin.